# CUDA Compilation error : Instruction '{atom,red}.shared' requires .target sm_12 or higher

Tags: c++, cuda

I am trying to get the minimum value from a collection of float values, by taking advantage of the Atomic operations provided by CUDA. . I cannot use reduction because of memory constraints. However, I get the error message: **Instruction '{atom,red}.shared' requires .target sm_12 or higher** when I try compiling the code below with a __Shared__ variable passed as the "SharedMem" arguement.

I have a 9400m GPU which has compute capability of 1.1.

```
__device__ static float* atomicMin(float* SharedMem, float value, float *old)
{
    old[0] = *SharedMem;
    float assumed;
    if (old[0] <= value)
    {
        return old;
    }

    do
    {
        assumed = old[0];
        old[0] = ::atomicCAS((unsigned int*)SharedMem, __float_as_int(assumed), __float_as_int(value));
    } while (old[0] != assumed);

    return old;
}
```

Take for example calling the function "getMin_Kernel" below:

```
__shared__ __device__ float LowestDistance;
__global__ void getMin_Kernel(float* AllFloats, int* NumberOfFloats)
{
    int j = (blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x);
    if (j < NumberOfFloats[0])
    {
        float myFloat;
        myFloat=*(atomicMin(&LowestDistance, NumberOfFloats[0], &myFloat));
    }

}
```

However, if I pass a non-shared variable it compiles without issues, however, I get a runtime error. I am guessing the run time error occurs because atomicCAS requires a global or shared variable. Can anyone please help with a way to get around the compilation error.

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you should read the [documentation about atomics](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions) and limit yourself to the instructions and cases that are supported by your cc1.1 GPU.  On your cc1.1 GPU, you cannot use atomics on shared variables.  It's not just a compile error, it's a limitation of your GPU.  If you want to focus on the "runtime error" you'll have to give quite a bit more detail in your question.

Comment: Your example makes no sense, you're passing an int to a float argument, the parameter old is pointless, etc. Also you haven't said what variable you are passing and what the runtime error is. Your example should be http://sscce.org. Besides that, as @RobertCrovella said you won't be able to do shared memory atomics with a sm_11 GPU.

Answer (score 1):

This table http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#features-and-technical-specifications__feature-support-per-compute-capability provides a full description of various compute capabilities and their matching feature support.

Thanks guys I didn't notice the extra bullet points in the documentation stating the conditions for atomicCas and shared memory variables. I'm still learning the ropes of CUDA.

Thanks.